# x86 instruction prefix decoding

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

I'm currently in the process of developing a disassembler for the x86_x64 CISC.
I have 2 questions regarding prefix instruction decoding:

1. For the following stream:

   ```
   \x9b\x9b\xd9\x30
   ```

   `GCC` and `objdump` outputs

   ```
   fstenv [eax]
   ```

   So they're first reading all prefixes
   (no more than 15) and then proceed to check the correct instruction
   using the last prefix read `\x9b` with `\xd9` to make it a `fstenv`
   instruction.

   `Capstone` on the other hand outputs

   ```
   wait
   wait
   fnstenv dword ptr [eax]
   ```

   Now, obviously capstone in on the wrong
   that it puts 2 `wait` instructions and not just 1. But should it put
   `wait` instructions at all or `GCC` and `objdump` is on the right
   here for consuming all the extra `\x9b` prefixes for the `fstenv`
   instruction?
2. For the following stream:

   ```
   \xf2\x66\x0f\x12\x00
   ```

   `GCC` and `objdump` output

   ```
   data16 movddup xmm0,QWORD PTR [eax]
   ```

   So they're arranging the
   prefixes in a specific order so `\x66` is interpreted before `\xf2`
   thus, and so they're still using the last prefix read `\xf2` to
   determine the instruction `movddup`. So is they're right here for
   using this arrange logic of the prefixes or are they wrong?

   `Capstone` on the other hand outputs

   `movlpd xmm0, qword ptr [eax]`

   So they're not arranging the prefixes in any order and they're just
   taking the last prefix read `\x66` to determine the instruction
   `movlpd` which looks more logical in this case than what `GCC` and
   `objdump` were doing.

How is the cpu **actually** interpreting these streams?

Comment: 1) `fstenv` does  not really exist. The instruction set reference says: _"The assembler issues two instructions for the FSTENV instruction (an FWAIT instruction followed by an FNSTENV instruction), and the processor executes each of these instructions separately."_ Capstone is technically correct.

Comment: There is a mandatory order for prefixes.  I forgot which one it is, but you can check the manual.  If the order of prefixes is wrong, behaviour is undefined.

Comment: The instruction set reference says: _"Instruction prefixes [...] may be placed in any order relative to each other."_ Note that `wait` is not a prefix.

Comment: 2) It's undefined to apply `F2` prefix to that instruction so it's hard to argue which version is correct. My cpu (amd ryzen 1700) seems to think objdump is right, it is executed as `movddup`. TBH, I expected it to be a `movlpd`...

Comment: Intel E5-2620 also thinks it's `movddup`.

Comment: @Jester [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197365/417501) claims that for SSE instructions, F2/F3 beat 66 if both groups appear.

Answer (score 5):

How your CPU actually interprets these streams can be tested relatively easily.

---

For the first stream, you can use my tool [nanoBench](https://github.com/andreas-abel/nanoBench). You can use the command

`sudo ./nanoBench.sh -asm_init "mov RAX, R14" -asm ".byte 0x9b, 0x9b, 0xd9, 0x30"`.

This command first sets `RAX` to a valid memory address, and then runs your stream multiple times. On my Core i7-8700K, I get the following output (for the fixed-function performance counters):

```
Instructions retired: 3.00
Core cycles: 73.00
Reference cycles: 62.70
```

We can see that the CPU executes three instructions, so `Capstone` seems to be correct.

---

You can analyze the second stream using the debug mode of nanoBench:

`sudo ./nanoBench.sh -unroll 1 -asm "mov RAX, R14; mov qword ptr [RAX], 1234; .byte 0xf2, 0x66, 0x0f, 0x12, 0x00" -debug`.

This will - inside `gdb` - first execute the `asm` code, and then generate a breakpoint trap. We can now look at the current value of the XMM0 register:

```
(gdb) p $xmm0.v2_int64
$1 = {1234, 1234}
```

So the high and the low quadword of XMM0 now have the same value as the memory at address RAX, which indicates that the CPU executed the `movddup` instruction.

---

You can also analyze the second stream without using nanoBench. To do this, you can save the following assembler code in a file `asm.s`.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.global _start
_start:
    mov RAX, RSP
    mov qword ptr [RAX], 1234   
    .byte 0xf2, 0x66, 0x0f, 0x12, 0x00
    int 0x03 /* breakpoint trap */
```

Then, you can build it using

```
as asm.s -o asm.o
ld -s asm.o -o asm
```

Now you can analyze it with gdb using `gdb ./asm`:

```
(gdb) r
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x0000000000400088 in ?? ()
(gdb) p $xmm0.v2_int64
$2 = {1234, 1234}
```

Comment: testing it with another disassembler doesn't gonna help if it should be `movddup` or `movlpd` it can be wrong as-well by arranging the prefixes doesn't it ?

Comment: @Jorayen the last example judges `movddup` vs `movlpd` based on the actual value in `xmm0` register, not by what disassembler shows. The `movlpd` would produce different result in register.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Linux enters user-space with XMM registers all zeroed, so we'd see `{0, 1234}` if it decoded as `movlpd`.

Answer (score 3):

`9B 9B D9 30` **Capstone is correct, and objdump's `fstenv` is also mostly correct.**

**`fstenv` isn't a real machine instruction**, it's a pseudo-instruction for `fwait` + `fnstenv`.  Notice that machine code for `fnstenv` listed [in the manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fstenv:fnstenv) is `D9 /6`, while `fstenv` adds a `9B` before that.

**`9B` is *not* an instruction prefix, it's a separate 1-byte instruction called [`wait` aka `fwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wait:fwait)**.  On original 8086+8087, this was necessary because 8087 was a truly separate coprocessor.  [How did the 8086 interface with the 8087 FPU coprocessor?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9173/how-did-the-8086-interface-with-the-8087-fpu-coprocessor/).  See the comments under the top answer there; before 286 they weren't tightly coupled enough for the main CPU to know if there were pending FPU exceptions.

I'm not sure of the details, but `fnstsw` on an 8086 / 186 could maybe read an old version of the status word that didn't have the latest flags set from a masked exception.  Or maybe it only matters with unmasked exceptions, for getting the FP exception from a multiply or whatever before the `fnst*` instruction.  According to Stephen Kitt's comments, 286 and newer "checks its TEST line before executing an NPX instruction", automatically FWAITing.

And of course CPUs with integrated FPUs have no trouble with precise FP exceptions, and synchronous behaviour, so `fwait` is a waste of space there.

---

Capstone's `wait` / `wait` / `fnstenv dword ptr [eax]` is thus more explicit, because as far as the CPU is concerned, it really is 3 instructions.  (As Andreas's answer shows modern x86 perf counters record).

Objdump treats two preceding `fwait` instructions as part of a single `fstenv`.  It would be more accurate to decode it as `fwait` ; `fstenv dword ptr [eax]` because Intel's manual only documents `fstenv` as including a single `fwait` opcode.  But an extra `fwait` has no architectural effect.

---

### Part 2

As Andreas's answer shows, `f2 66 0f 12 00` decodes as a `movddup` (64-bit broadcast) on real hardware, with a meaningless `66` (data16 operand-size) prefix.  **objdump is correct, at least for that CPU**.

The documented encoding for [`movddup` is `F2 0F 12`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movddup), where F2 is a mandatory prefix, and 0F is the escape byte.

We might have expected it to decode as [`66 0F 12 /r MOVLPD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movlpd) with a meaningless F2 REP prefix, but that's not the case; **capstone is wrong**.  There are rules for mandatory prefix bytes: [order for encoding x86 instruction prefix bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197282/order-for-encoding-x86-instruction-prefix-bytes/7197365#7197365) including "the 66 prefix is ignored if either F2 or F3 are used".

I'm not 100% sure this sequence is *guaranteed* to decode as `movddup` on all hardware, of if this is merely how Intel Sandybridge-family happens to decode it.  As @fuz commented, there is a required order for mandatory prefixes and getting it wrong gives undefined behaviour (i.e. a specific CPU might decode it to anything, especially some future CPU where a different sequence of prefixes is mandatory for some other instruction.)

Comment: Did you find which section of the manual describes the ordering rules? As fuz also complained in comments under the linked question, I can't find anything about mandatory order in the manual version I have either.

Comment: @Jester: No, I made that part up / parroted \@fuz. >.<  I didn't go digging in the manual.